# Code works in Debug mode by not while running

Tags: vba

I have gone through this many answers for this question but didnt find a solution. could someone help?

The below code works only in Debug mode (F8) and not when run.

CODE :

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D7").Value
Dim wb01 As Workbook
Set wb01 = ActiveWorkbook
wb01.Sheets(1).Range("B1").EntireColumn.Copy
Range("A1").Insert shift:=xlToRight
Columns("C").Delete
Range("C1").Sort key1:=Range("C1"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes

Dim LAROW As Long
LAROW = wb01.Sheets(1).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Activate
Dim Finalrow As Long
Finalrow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim j As Integer


For j = 3 To Finalrow
On Error Resume Next


Range("F" & j).Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(WorksheetFunction.Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("B" & j).Value), wb01.Sheets(1).Range("A2:C" & LAROW), 2, 0)
Debug.Print
Next
```

Comment: What do you mean with "does not work"? And pls check the code you pasted, it is not complete - look at the line `Range("F" & j).Value =`

Comment: Hi FunThomas, it dosent do what it actually should do. if you go through the code you will understand. its just copy paste and vlookup

Comment: Sorry, if you don't explain at least what the code *should* do and what it actualliy does instead, how do you expect us to help you?

Comment: FunThomas, the first part of the code is just copying one column and replacing it to another column and sort colum "C" in the activeworkbook.  The last part is Vlookup from the Activeworkbook already set to the Thiswokbook(where the code lies)

Comment: You still don't tell us what is not working as expected...

Comment: The code does not do the process when i run it.. only does when i go in debug mode. It DOES NOT DO ANY STEPS when run. Hope you got it.

Comment: Do you mean the output comes just in degub mode? If this is the case, then you are right because the command `Debug.Print` just displays the output in the debug window. If you want to display something on your sheet use `Msgbox "Test"`

Comment: If it does nothing then I'd suggest the method you're using to run it is wrong.  What do you do to make it run when not in debug mode?  Shouting doesn't make people particularly want to help..

Comment: i would press F8 to check each line. when i run on the whole i wonder why it dosent work. and sorry if my tone sounded so, i was not shouting. :)

Comment: `F8` (or `F5`) runs it in debug mode - but how do you try and run it normally (when it does nothing)?  A worksheet/workbook event, on a click of a button, clicking `Run` on the macro dialog box?

Comment: yeah.. i click a button to run the full code.

Comment: Is the button working correctly?  If it's a form control button has it got the correct macro assigned to it, if it's an activeX button is the `Private Sub` named the same as the button name and does it call the correct code?  Are you still in `Design Mode` so that you select the button rather than click it?